# What is causing my Python program to run out of memory using opencv?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, memory

I wrote a program to read images using Python's opencv and tried to load 3 GB images, but the program aborted.
There is 32 GB of memory on my PC, but when I run this program it will run out of it. What is the cause?

The error message is not issued and the PC becomes abnormally heavy. I confirmed it with Ubuntu's System Monitor, and it ran out of memory and swap.

I import images into one array to pass to tensorflow deep learning program. The size of the images are 200 x 200 color images.

I use 64 bit version of Python.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

IMG_SIZE = 200


def read_images(path):
    dirnames = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    files = [sorted(os.listdir(path+dirnames[i]))\
         for i in range(len(dirnames))]
    i = 0
    images = []
    for fs in files:
        tmp_images = []
        for f in fs:
            img = cv2.imread(path +dirnames[i] + "/" + f)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            img = img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0
            tmp_images.append(img)
        i = i + 1
        images.append(tmp_images)

    return np.asarray(images)
```

Comment: Please post the error message you get.

Comment: are you using a 32 bit version of Python or 64 bit?

Comment: I use 64bit version.

Comment: The error message is not issued and the PC becomes abnormally heavy.
I confirmed it with ubuntu 's System Monitor, and it ran out of memory and swap.

Comment: An image being 2 MB on your system does not mean it will be 2 MB when loaded into OpenCV. There is overhead since a `np.ndarray` holds more information, and additionally, you're converting it to `float32` instead of the native `uint8`, which means that you're using *four times* the memory for each image. You could just convert when you use each image. You probably don't *need* to load 3 GB of images into a single array, so what are you exactly trying to do? It's not clear how large the images are being resized from either, so hard to give precise advice here.

Comment: In addition to the above, images stored on your disk as PNG or JPEG are compressed by the nature of those formats, and `imread` decompresses them to put the data into an array.

Comment: I  import images into one array to pass to tenosorflow deep learning program.
The size of the images are 200 x 200 color images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons for running out of memory:

- Image file size and the size of corresponding array in memory are different. Images, e.g., PNG and JPEG formats, are compressed. The size of a corresponding uncompressed BMP image is more relevant here. Also, `ndarray` holds some meta-information that makes it a bit larger.
- Converting to `float32` from `uint8` multiplies the size by 4. Try to avoid this if possible (I recognize `uint8` imposes some limitations, like being unable to normalize and center the data).

Possible remedies:

- Use [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create an array stored on disk
- Reduce the quality of images, by converting to grayscale and/or reducing the resolution.
- Train the model on a smaller number of images.